# Android: Where to store Selector (xml) file for customed design controls

Tags: java, android

I tried to make a custom LinearLayout and Button styles.

I'm just wondering where to place my Selector xml files?

```
<selector     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient 
            android:angle="90"  
            android:startColor="#534E4E"
            android:endColor="#000000"
            android:type="linear" />

    </shape>
</item>
```

In my mono project I put the files at drawable folder BUT in my Java(native) development I don't know maybe I miss the basic in storing files but still have no Idea where to put my Selector since the latest Eclipse plugin has 4 drawables (-ldpi,-hdpi, mdpi and xhdpi).

Comment: just create a folder with no specifier called `/drawable`

Comment: There is no good practice or ways for organizing drawables in android. They have to be cluttered. It's dumb, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Create a drawable/ folder in the res/ directory and add the selector.xml files in there.

Comment: I just found same issue and answered that way. Is this still valid? I mean I know it is valid but is it suggested as a best practice?

Comment: In Eclipse when you use the Wizard to make a New Android XML File and choose selector, it generates it in the drawable/ folder.

Comment: What if the selector just contains color tag? Should I put it in color folder?

Answer (score -3):

Place it in all the drawable folders so that the image adjust in different size phones. That worked for me.

Comment: Actually why should you use multiple selectors? Just one selector with multiple images in corresponding density buckets will do the job.